# Figcaption no wider than the image

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where the `figcaption` is wider than the `img` and hence sticking out to the right of it. I hardcoded the `width` of the caption and it works, but only for images of the same width.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/tVeUqlH.jpg"/>
        <figcaption>Vader enjoying the beach.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
figure {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 10px;
}
figure img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
figcaption {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    width: 120px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7q1y9k8w/2/)**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `display: table-caption;`.

```css
.imagecaption {
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
figure {
    display: table;
    margin: 0px;

}

figure img {
    display: block;
}

figcaption {
    display: table-caption;
    caption-side: bottom;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagecaption">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/tVeUqlH.jpg"/>
    <figcaption>Vader enjoying the beach.</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. this works well. Except that the border no longer includes the text.

Comment: I just added a wrapper div around the whole thing so I got it now.

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry for the delay. Answer edited with outside div.